# When does Spring creates proxies in the bean's lifecycle?

Tags: spring

If I am using Spring AOP, at which point in the applicationcontext lifecycle proxies get created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the bean instances are created they are run through a series of [BeanPostProcessors](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanPostProcessor.html) - Based on the AOP advice, the proxies are created by a [BeanPostProcessor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanPostProcessor.html) called [AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/aop/aspectj/annotation/AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.html) (or possibly its subclasses)