# Spring and Guice: when DI frameworks create proxies?

Tags: java, spring, proxy, guice

We know that DI frameworks, such as Spring and Guice sometimes create proxies instead of beans. To compare these proxies in equals and hashcode methods we should use instanceOf operator, because their class is not longer the same as the original one. 
Also (may be) these proxies may be created in some uninitialized state just like Hibernate proxies (its just my guess).

I know only one case when Spring creates proxy of a bean: when you annotate it with @Configuration. 
Is there any other situations like that?
Does Spring create uninitialized proxies which only initialize their fields once that fields are accessed?

I have found a similair question: [When does Spring creates proxies in the bean's lifecycle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648394/when-does-spring-creates-proxies-in-the-beans-lifecycle), but please note that it relates to AOP usage case. I am asking about simple DI usage without AOP involved.

Same question for Guice!

Comment: Guice doesn't generally create any proxy unless there is AOP involved or to solve the circular dependency problem (and then only if the binding is on a class, not on an interface).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring uses proxies every time you use annotations like `@Transactional` or `@Cacheable`. It's AOP has nothing to do with the complex AOP that requires a post compile or weaving.

Anyway, be aware that if in one of your *services* you've autowired a *repository*, and inside the *service* you create a class where you set the *repository*, this will be automatically used as a proxy (if there's an annotation that requires it).

About Guice, the answer is in the comment of @Oliver.

Answer (score 1):

In HK2 whether or not proxies are made for injection points depends on the scope/context of the bean being injected.  In particular, in HK2 a scope can be annotated with [Proxiable](https://hk2.java.net/2.5.0-b23/apidocs/org/glassfish/hk2/api/Proxiable.html).  You can control with the [Proxiable](https://hk2.java.net/2.5.0-b23/apidocs/org/glassfish/hk2/api/Proxiable.html) annotation whether or not proxies should be generated for injections of beans into other beans of the same scope.

You can further control whether beans in non-proxiable scopes DO get proxied or beans in proxiable scopes should NOT be proxied with the annotations [Unproxiable](https://hk2.java.net/2.5.0-b23/apidocs/org/glassfish/hk2/api/Unproxiable.html) and [UseProxy](https://hk2.java.net/2.5.0-b23/apidocs/org/glassfish/hk2/api/UseProxy.html).  There are equivalent verbs in the EDSL as well (for example [ServiceBindingBuilder.proxyForSameScope](https://hk2.java.net/2.5.0-b23/apidocs/org/glassfish/hk2/utilities/binding/ServiceBindingBuilder.html#proxyForSameScope(boolean))).

In additions proxies would be generated by HK2 if AOP was in play

Answer (score 1):

Assisted injection in Guice might be a use-case that could be of interest to you. Long story very short.

Factory interface:

```
public interface PaymentFactory {
  public Payment create(Date startDate, Money amount);
}
```

Payment implementation:

```
public class RealPayment implements Payment {
  @Inject
  public RealPayment(
        CreditService creditService,
        AuthService authService,
        @Assisted Date startDate,
        @Assisted Money amount);
  }
  ...
}
```

Binding:

```
install(new FactoryModuleBuilder()
     .implement(Payment.class, RealPayment.class)
     .build(PaymentFactory.class));
```

Guice will then generate the `PaymentFactory` implementation for you.

More details and the complete exapmple are available in the [wiki](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/AssistedInject). Note: this is a guice extension. I'm not aware of more Guice use cases except those mentioned by Olivier Grégoire in his comment.